# How to use FactoryGirl with ActiveRecord transaction rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, factory-bot

I Use Factory Girl a lot to create fake data in my database. But whenever I create a new factory and if a error occurs I end up with lot of inconsistent data since it does not support transaction no rollback occurs
For example (snapshot of console)

```
INSERT INTO `INVOICES` (`created_by`, `creation_date`, `fulfillment_branch_id`, `invoice_date`, `invoice_number`, `invoice_status`, `last_updated`, `last_updated_by`, `order_id`, `order_status`, `parent_order_id`) VALUES ('xx.xx@xx.net', '2015-07-16 11:27:00', '1035280', NULL, NULL, 'Active', '2015-07-16 11:27:00', 'xx.xx@xx.net', 24, 'Invoiced', NULL)

  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO `packages` (`created_at`, `created_by`, `shipment_id`, `size`, `status`, `updated_at`, `updated_by`, `value`, `weight`) VALUES ('2015-07-16 11:27:00', 49, NULL, 'LBH', 'active', '2015-07-16 11:27:00', 49, 2448.0, 0.32950726052542545)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'shipment_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `packages` (`created_at`, `created_by`, `shipment_id`, `size`, `status`, `updated_at`, `updated_by`, `value`, `weight`) VALUES ('2015-07-16 11:27:00', 49, NULL, 'LBH', 'active', '2015-07-16 11:27:00', 49, 2448.0, 0.32950726052542545)
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `block in execute'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/db-charmer-1.9.0/lib/db_charmer/rails3/abstract_adapter/connection_name.rb:14:in `instrument'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `execute'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:211:in `execute'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:234:in `exec_insert'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:90:in `insert'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `insert'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation.rb:66:in `insert'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:367:in `create'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:58:in `create'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:268:in `block in create'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__221280857__create__997484455__callbacks'
... 58 levels...
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/observer.rb:194:in `notify_observers'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:20:in `notify'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:13:in `block in result'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `tap'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:23:in `block in run'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
    from (irb):4
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/infibeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@pipes/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from scripFactoryGirl.reload
```

Can anyone explain where I should monkey patch to ensure factory runs transactionally?

### Edit

To clear my question I want to patch FactoryGirl module so that my FactoryGirl.create api gets  wrapped in ActiveRecord transaction everytime I call it.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean while running it creates records in the database and if it fails it keeps records in the database? If this is the case use database cleaner to avoid this

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just wrap your data creation in a transaction? Typically FactoryGirl would be used in the test environment where it doesn't matter so much if it fails as the database will be cleaned anyway. Or, if you are using it in seeds, you can wrap your calls in a transaction. If you're creating data through the console it might be more repeatable to do it in a seed file anyway.

Comment: I sometimes use FactoryGirl in development to create fake data but in the process most of the time I end with a lot of inconsistent data

Answer (score 1):

The reason of this error it's that you set for package table

```
shipment_id: nil
```

To solve this you should set some info for this. Example:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :example do
    shipment

    #your another code
```

where is shipment - is association for Shipment-model

Comment: The error is just giving an example of the problem. The question is not looking for a fix for the error itself - it is looking for a solution to the knock-on effects that the error causes.

Comment: thanks... It was just an example but I needed more of a general solution of how can you wrap my FactoryGirl call around ActiveRecord transaction